# remote permission denied Github

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to upload my repo on github and go through:

git push -u origin master

at that point it gives me the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\pc\OneDrive\Pictures\wfh_cms> git push origin master        
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
remote: Permission to zubairmukhtar/wfh.git denied to zubair-syslab.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/zubairmukhtar92/wfh.git/': The requested URL returned 
error: 403
```

Comment: Okay, and now what do you want to ask?

Comment: i am trying to push my project into github it gives me error

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status 403 is "Unauthorized": you've provided valid credentials, but you do not have permission to do the requested action. Make sure you've granted write access on that repo to the `zubair-syslab` user, and that that user is allowed to push directly to that branch.